# Curl does not create cookies (special case)

Tags: php, curl, cookies

It always works when curl use and do use some of my scripts, it works.
But when I try to do with the script that just did not work. It gives me php errors. I have enabled redirect in the Apache configuration file. File permissions are 666, the directory is full, etc ...

I have researched this problem for 4 hours without finding a solution...

index.php:

```
 <?php
 $config['brower'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36';
 $config['cookie_fb'] = getcwd().'/cookie_fb.txt';

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/'.(isset($_GET['url_data']) ? $_GET['url_data'] : ''));
 if(isset($_POST)) {
    //echo http_build_query($_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 }
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $config['cookie_fb']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $config['cookie_fb']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['brower']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.com');

 $html = curl_exec($ch);

 $facebookText = array(
    'https://www.facebook.com/',
 );
 $customText = array(
    'http://localhost/',
 );

 echo str_replace($facebookText, $customText, $html);

 curl_close($ch);
 unset($ch);
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_data=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please show your code here.

Comment: The editor sucks, pls it one click...

Comment: @Magic...: (In the future, use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.)

Comment: The editor is fine. Paste your code, select it with the mouse, and click on the `{}` tool or type Ctl-k to mark it as code.

Comment: What php errors are you getting?

Comment: write permission problem?

Comment: 666 is the permission of index.php